# What is that thing in the liquid?

Tags: dc, aliens, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, lex-luthor

In Batman v Superman, in the part of the crashed Kryptonian ship where

> Lex uses Zods body and his DNA with Kryptonian tech to create Doomsday

There seems to be a living thing swimming around in the liquid that Lex is standing in. Is that thing alive, or is it part of the Kryptonian ship like that other unit which follows Lex around? If neither of those are true then, what is it?

Comment: who knowns, some form of magical movie nonsense that doesnt make sense, because reasons

Comment: wouldn't be unlike Zack Snyder...

Comment: To me it looked like a shape similar to ship's hovering drone, with tentacles attached. It may be impossible to tell for sure until there's a home video release...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It's a Kryptonian bot

Unfortunately, it's too early to provide a screenshot or script direction, but I've made a careful note of the scenes involving General Zod's body and the birth of Doomsday within the Kryptonian ship.

Ignoring the Kryptonian hover-bot floating above the liquid that Zod is lowered into, and also ignoring the various cables / tentacles that descend from the ceiling of the chamber that seem to wrap around Zod's body, I can confirm that there *is* something swimming in the liquid.

It's quite clearly another Kryptonian bot, oriented horizontally rather than vertically.  The length and width are identical to that of the hover-bot and it has an identically-shaped upper half as the hover-bot.  But its lower half consists of approximately eight appendages that permit it to flagellate through the liquid.  (The flagellation gives it an impression of being alive.)

[image]

^ *Has the same top half as this but a different bottom half...*

**NOTE:** This is un update of a previous answer.  The original answer was written after a single viewing of *BvS*.  I've updated it more conclusively after a second viewing.  (Some might question the wisdom of seeing it twice, but what's done is done.)

Comment: I am not talking about the mechanical thing hovering in the corner... There was a scene that clearly showed something swimming under the water/liquid in the chamber... and it did not look much like the above picture. It is considerably smaller.

Comment: @Theyna : I still contend that it was something mechanical, not biological (as recognizer also mentioned in comments).  But we might have to wait and see.  :-)

Comment: quite possible, but yes... if no one knows right now we may simply have to wait

Comment: @Theyna : I've watched *BvS* again, making sure to study on those scenes carefully.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: It is a bot. There is nothing else alive on this ship. The bots design was merely naturally-inspired to facilitate movement without unduly disturbing the medium.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze : Exactly.  Glad you agree.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Great commitment to finding the answer! I appreciate your willingness to see it a second time.

Comment: @Theyna : Thanks!  To be honest, I think I enjoyed it more the second time around.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's an [AquaBot](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Aquabots)
[image]

"Aquabots were working, pruning ready embryos, thereby maintaining the chamber.

On the Scout Ship, General Zod activates the ship's Genesis Chamber which activates the Aquabots into action, as they begin to maintain and treat the precious embryos inside. However, they were most likely all damaged beyond repair when Kal-El destroyed the chamber with his heat vision.

Aquabots survived the crashed Scout Scout ship, moving around inside the crashed Genesis Chamber whilst Alexander Luthor, Jr. placed the dead body of Zod into the Chamber's waters along with his own blood, to create Doomsday."